# Unable to pass the JSESSIONID to the another scenario in karate

Tags: api, testing, automation, karate

I am trying to store the JSESSIONID  in a variable and passing a JSession variable to the another scenario where I am unable to get the success response .Below the steps that I have followed

@jCookieId
Scenario: SC01
Given path 'google/API'
When method post
Then status 200

- def JSessionID = responseCookies.JSESSIONID.value
- print 'check this -->',JSessionID

Scenario: SC02
Given path 'test/API'
* def sessionId = karate.call ('file:features/aa.feature@jCookieId')
* cookie JSESSIONID = sessionId.JSessionID

Error:{
"ErrCode": "710000",
"status": 0,
"ErrMsg": "An unknown error occurred while processing the request",
"httpStatusCode": 200
}

Note: I am new to karate and am sure that I am missing some important logic here. I would really appreciate any solution to this problem

Thank you!!

Comment: you are certainly missing something. search other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+jsessionid